# Best way to download multiple files from S3 - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I have zips in s3 with videos.. some are small (3Mb), but others can be bigger (like 30Mb).. I need to download these zips.. I don't know what is the best way to do it, talking about performance.. Put these videos in a unique zip and download just one zip with all the videos in it or download every file separately.. Joining and compacting the files to a zip in a temp folder isn't expensive in performance or much work for the server?

PS.: The user will choose the videos that he wants to be downloaded and click on a button to download them (I think it would be like  10-100 videos)..

Answer (score 1):

From a strictly performance standpoint, downloading straight from S3 beats everything else hands down as it's no load on the rails box.  It doesn't often meet other considerations like security, logging, access control, etc.

Comment: Yes, but I have many zip files on S3 that I would like to download... Is there a way to do it just with a single click on a button? My idea was to join the files of these zips in a singular bigger zip and download just this bigger zip.

Comment: A quick google suggests that there isn't a built in way on S3 to zip files into bundles.
If you know the pattern of the bundles, you can make them before upload... or if you don't or it's likely that they won't be downloaded you can build them on demand and cache them.

Comment: I don't know if I understood.. you mean to save this bigger zip on S3 instead of the little ones and just download it directly from S3?

Comment: It's an option.  Depending on your needs/wants you might be okay with using more space on S3 for less load on the rails server.
It's really a matter of figuring out the actual value of what's important in your situation and adapting your solution to maximize.